# AngularJS Expression Not Displaying

Tags: angularjs

I'm simply trying to get an AngularJS expression to display on screen. However, nothing shows up between the curly braces. I've inspected the app with ng-inspector and although I see an object being created with an ng-model directive, I can't display the value with the object key.

Furthermore, for testing purposes, I can't even get a simple math expression to display either.

Here's what I'm working with.

```
<body ng-app="angularApp">
    <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
      <input ng-model="project.completed" type="checkbox">
      <input ng-model="project.title" type="text" placeholder="Project Title">
      <label>
          {{project.title}}
          1+2={{1 + 2}}
      </label>
      <input ng-model="project.time" type="text" placeholder="Project Time">
      <label for="">{{project.time}}</label>
      <button ng-click="helloWorld()">Press Me</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

...and here's the controller:

```
angular.module('angularApp', [])

.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.helloWorld = function() {
        console.log('You just pressed the button.');
    };

    $scope.project = {
        completed :false,
        title :'test',
    };

});
```

The only thing that shows up in the label is '1+2='.

UPDATE: After spending a ridiculous amount of time trying to debug this I have been able to get the first value of the math expression to display -- the '1'. I achieved this by adding a space around the '+' operator. Still, the full expression is not evaluating.

Comment: post your controller

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Do you have somewhere `ng-app="angularApp"`?

Comment: No console errors @OmriAharon.

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4aqn3f1q/).

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks for taking a look - I viewed your demo and it appears to be the same code as I have listed in the initial question. Is there a change to the code that I missed?

Comment: It is the same code as your question with no changes. It uses AngularJS 1.4.8. And the default settings for `$interpolateProvider`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using another templating engine, such as Twig, Liquid, or Django, the curly braces may be being stripped out. This results in the values not displaying or evaluating properly.

The solution I found is editing the interpolation characters or $interpolateProvider like so inside your controller:

```
angular.module('angularApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
})
```

Then, just wrap your expression in the new symbols, e.g.:

```
{[{ 1+2 }]}
```

...or

```
{[{ project.title }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally found it, simply open your web page and press f12 and view the console :) Also remove any unused css. Additionally make sure that you add the "ng-controller" in the  tag or some other broad scope so its well covered within the scope.